# Pass row index to modal popup window from buttonField in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, modalpopupextender

I have a GridView (see below) which uses ButtonField buttons to launch modal popup windows.
Here is the GridView

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_ButtonClick"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="mGrid" AllowPaging="True" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"  
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" CssClass="alt" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="BeaconID" ShowHeader="True" Visible="True" DataField="beaconObjectid" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="aliasName" HeaderText="My Beacon Name" />
                            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="AssignName" Text="Assign Name"/>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Action Type" DataField="actionType" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="actionContent" HeaderText="Action Content" />
                            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="AssignAction" Text="Assign/Change Action"/>

                        </Columns>
                        <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

This works fine to open the modal window like this one, using the C# code shown further down:

```
 <asp:Button ID="showModal3" runat="server" Text="Show Modal"  CssClass="hiddenButton"/>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup">
        <div class="header">
        Set Alias Name
    </div>
        <div class="body">
            Set a new name for your beacon
            <br />

            <br />

            <div style="float: none;">
               <asp:TextBox ID="AliasNameTextBox" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox> 
            </div>

            </div><br/>

         <div class="footer" align="right">
        <asp:Button ID="setAliasOK" runat="server" Text="OK" CssClass="yes" OnClick="setAliasOK_Click" CausesValidation="False" />
        <asp:Button ID="setAliasCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="no" />
    </div></asp:Panel>
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="SetAliasNameModalPopupExtender" runat="server" CancelControlID="setAliasCancel" DropShadow="True" PopupControlID="Panel3" TargetControlID="showModal3" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

In my C# code, i'm getting the index of the buttons like this so i know which row was clicked, which all works well:

```
   protected void GridView1_ButtonClick(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)]; // this gets the row
            string id = row.Cells[0].Text;
            string name = row.Cells[1].Text;
            string actionText = row.Cells[3].Text;

            if (e.CommandName == "AssignName")
            {
                SetAliasNameModalPopupExtender.Show();
                AliasNameTextBox.Text = name;
            }

            if (e.CommandName == "AssignAction")
            {
                ChooseActionModalPopupExtender.Show();
            }

            Label1.Text = name;
            Label2.Text = actionText;
            Label3.Text = id;

            currentlySelectedRow = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            beaconIDnumber = id;
        }
```

The problem is when i click the 'OK' button from my **modal** popup window. I need to have access to the row index from the gridview buttonfield that called it. My OK button click event looks like this:

```
protected void setAliasOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           var newName = AliasNameTextBox.Text;

            ParseChangeAliasName(beaconIDnumber, newName);

            SetAliasNameModalPopupExtender.Hide();
        }
```

So ultimately what i'm asking, is how do i pass the gridview row to the modal window so i can use data from the respective row cell - in this case the beacon ID (DataField="beaconObjectid" in the gridview).
I've even tried setting global variables in the GridView1_ButtonClick method, and then referencing them in the setAliasOK_Click method, but they get wiped as soon as the modal window opens.
Ideally i want to do this without using Javascript if possible.

Answer (score 0):

in the same way you get

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
```

you can set your Button attributes:

```
setAliasOK.CommandName = "AliasOK" ;
setAliasOK.CommandArgument = e.CommandArgument ;
```

But you need to process your button's RowCommand event rather than the Click event to get to the Button's Command parameters